# How to use variables of git submodule foreach in gitpython

Tags: python, git, git-submodules, gitpython

Using [gitpython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), I would like to use `repo.git.submodule('foreach', …)` and get the variables available such as `name`, `sm_path`, `displaypath`, `sha1` and `toplevel` as defined in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt).

I couldn't find any documentation on gitpython and my understanding of the API is limited.

Comment: I cross posted in the repo directly and will post here if anything pops up there https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [stsewd](https://github.com/stsewd) [reply](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/886#issuecomment-505957095) on Github issue, one should write

```
repo = git.Repo('foo/bar')
for sub in repo.submodules:
    pass
```

and the documentation: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.submodules